# Which are the advantatges of using Template in Ktor in HTML DSL?

Tags: kotlin, ktor

I've just started learning Ktor, and I really like the use of the HTML DSL. Reading the docs (https://ktor.io/docs/html-dsl.html#templates) I've seen that there is a Templates﻿ engine. However, either there is something that I can't see, or I don't find the advantages of using it. Isn't cleaner and easier to use standard Kotlin extension functions, like the Div, P,... instead?

I post an example of how I would write the example on the tutorial using functions (the template example can be found [here](https://github.com/ktorio/ktor-documentation/blob/main/codeSnippets/snippets/html-templates/src/main/kotlin/com/example/Application.kt)):

```
fun Application.configureRouting() {
    configureArticleRouting()
    routing {
        get("/") {
            val name = "Ktor"
            call.respondHtml(HttpStatusCode.OK) {
                mainLayout(title = name){
                    articleContent(Article("Article Title", "My article content"))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

fun FlowContent.articleContent(article: Article) {
    article {
        h2 {
            +article.title
        }
        p {
            +article.content
        }
    }
}

fun HTML.mainLayout(title: String, content: FlowContent.() -> Unit) {
    head {
        title {
            +title
        }
    }
    body {
        content()
    }
}

data class Article(val title: String, val content: String)
```

The question is, what is the advantage of using templates?

Thanks,

Comment: It's just a different way of rendering HTML. The one advantage I see is that you can render any text with templates (HTML, CSS, etc.).

Comment: @AlekseiTirman If there is a second way of rendering HTML (which is more complex) I expect at least to have an small advantage, otherwise I don't see the point of the technology.
If it can render CSS is more versatile, but I don't see the advantage. I think that writing CSS in the function way would be also easier than using templates

Comment: In my opinion, HTML DSL is more complicated than templates so I would list it as an advantage.

Answer (score 0):

An advantage of using templates is that designers without profound programming skills can do the layout